# Error 403 when testing api rest with role based authentication

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot-security

I made a simple api rest application with role based authentication.
When I text the endpoints in postman or swagger if I put role restrictions I get the 403 error even if I log in with the user that has the appropriate role.

Class SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                       authorize.requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                                //.requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                             //.requestMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        return http.build();
    }


}
```

Class AuthController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    /**
     *
     * @param loginDto
     * @return
     */


    @PostMapping("/v1/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                loginDto.getEmail(), loginDto.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User signed-in successfully!.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param signUpDto
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping("/v1/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody @Validated SignUpDto signUpDto){



        // add check for email exists in DB


        if(userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpDto.getEmail())){
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Email già in uso scegli una mail diversa!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // create user object
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(signUpDto.getName());
        user.setSurname(signUpDto.getSurname());
        user.setEmail(signUpDto.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(signUpDto.getPassword()));
        user.setEnabled(true);

        Role roles = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER").get();
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(roles));

        userRepository.save(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Nuovo utente registrato correttamente!", HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

Class CustomUserDetailService

```
  @Service
    public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

        private UserRepository userRepository;

        public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                    .orElseThrow(() ->
                            new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email: "+ email));

            Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user
                    .getRoles()
                    .stream()
                    .map((role) -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());

            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    authorities);
        }
    }
```

Class User

```
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String name;


    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String surname;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 1)
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;


   /* @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "Booking",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "booking_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Booking> bookings;*/


}
```

Class Role

```
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String name;



}
```

Only with permitAll() I'm able to access the endpoints.

[Login ok[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qd8d.jpg)

[Error 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITVvn.jpg)

[Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxeeB.jpg)

Comment: can you try to save your roles without prefix "ROLE_" ?

Comment: it does'nt works